# An [emulator] to [emulate] [emulation]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are three similar tags on Stack Overflow, [emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulator), [emulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulate), and [emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulation).

- [emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulator): **2,929 questions tagged**, with the wiki:

  > An emulator is a system which is designed to perform the duties of a different system.
- [emulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulate): **95 questions tagged**, with the wiki:

  > Reproduce a computer system function or software activity via a different hardware or software component/emulator.
- [emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulation): **376 questions tagged**, with the wiki:

  > Emulation refers to the ability of a computer program in an electronic device to emulate (imitate) another program or device.

Are they the same thing? Should we merge them?

Comment: Not a dumb question at all. As for the synonym, I'm torn. Based on numbers the latter two should probably be synonymized with [tag:emulator]. On the other hand, the word "emulation" itself sort of covers the most ground and might be a better target for the synonyms as far as English goes.

Comment: Are you proposing that some of these be elumanated?

Comment: Additionally can we virtually virtualize [tag:virtualization] through emulation?

Comment: Welcome to SO and Meta. =)

Answer (score 28):

I don't see any difference between those tags.

[emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulator) is more used, but personally I find [emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulation) better.

I would rather go for setting [emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulator) and [emulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulate) as synonyms of [emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulation), as suggested by [*Jason C*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348640/an-emulator-to-emulate-emulation#comment470030_348640) in comments.

Comment: Well, they have not been marked as synonyms yet, anyway... will action be taken?

Comment: Done now, following this advice. [[tag:emulator]] is the "master" tag; the others are synonyms of it.

Comment: That wasn't the advice! :)  I think most agreed that [tag:emulation] should be the primary.

Comment: @RatherNotsay Oops! Sorry. I did the merge correctly, just wrote the comment incorrectly. [tag:emulation] is indeed the primary tag.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to recognize that [emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulator) can mean two very different, yet on-topic things:

- A software running on one system, designed to run programs designed for another system.
- A trouble-shooting tool used for real-time debugging/tracing of programs running live on a processor. These are often referred to as "in-circuit emulators".

I think the current tag wiki fails to mention this. The question is if it is a good tag in the first place, since it has ambiguous meanings.

Comment: I think the second (in-circuit emulator) usage is better left to [tag:debugging], and all such use of [tag:emulator] corrected to that.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver No, because a debugger is traditionally something that interrupts the program and disrupts the real-time. They are different tools. It is just that nowadays there's JTAG which lives somewhere between traditional debugging and real-time trace. Which has made traditional in-circuit emulators far less popular nowadays -  yet questions about them remain on-topic.

Comment: That being said, "debugging" and "emulator" are both pretty bad tags, since they are so broad.

Comment: Before I pull the trigger on what seems like a very reasonable synonymization, I just want to clarify what you're saying here. Do you think that [tag:emulator] should be preserved separately of [tag:emulation]? Because I am considering just making all of these synonyms of the master tag [tag:emulation]. Would that not adequately cover meaning #2?

Comment: @CodyGray Probably it doesn't matter. The task of using a (trouble-shooting) emulator is usually just called debugging. But these are more and more a thing of the past, I can barely find any questions about them on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I propose that we [emulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulate) the [emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulation) in the [emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulator) to solve this. Make [emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulator) the real one, and everything else synonyms. Have to keep them around, or someone will re-spawn them again anyway.

A couple quick peeks at the tag list (no way am I going to do a full review) seems to show a favored position for nouns over other parts of speech, and the name of the tool over the name of the process. As always, exceptions abound, however, [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugging) for example, which can be verb or noun. (I'm not an English language expert, so that could be wrong anyway.) Be that as it may, my vote is for [emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulator) to lead the charge, and the others to tag along.

Comment: Useful peeks. I like your thinking. To clarify: "Debugging" is the present participle of the verb "debug". In different contexts, it 'plugs into the sentence as' (has the return type of?) an adjective or a noun. (I can't remember the linguistic terminology for this.) In other words, although it is _derived_ from a verb, it may be _used_ as an adjective (compare "the programmer is debugging" with "the programmer is frustrated") or as a noun (as in "I'd better get on with my debugging.") There may be other parts of speech a present participle can behave as, but I can't think of examples.

Comment: Although I am a native speaker of English, I still find its rules odd at times. In this situation I believe _debugging_ is most likely a _gerund_, though it may be a _verbal noun_, and which it is just might depend on the usage. As loose as it is, in comparison to English, Perl seems like a strict language. I'll take Perl over English every chance I get. :). Now, how can we emulate English in Perl?

Comment: "emulation" is a noun.

Comment: @ThomasPoole Or, you know, removing [actual bugs](http://rur-ple.sourceforge.net/images/first_bug.jpg).

Comment: "emulate English in Perl?"

Well first I'd add a parenthesis-heavy markup system to distinguish for instance,

`(Time flies) (like (an arrow))` from `Time (flies ([that are] like (an arrow)))` from `(Time flies) (like (an arrow) [would]))` from `(Time flies) (like [you would time] (an arrow)` from `(Time [traveller] flies) like/are-fond-of ([the occasional] arrow)` and so on

Comment: That's the benefit of Perl, usually don't need all that markup, it _just does the right thing_.